# cut videos and merge them using Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a doubt.I have two videos and want to cut the 0 to 10 minutes video from first video,10 to 20 minutes video from second video.After that I want to merge the two splitted videos into one video.So Kindly help me how to do this for iOS?

Any help is greatful.

Comment: What is your target platform: Mac OS or iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at AVFoundation reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) for general video loading with single frame access classes.

Especially at the "[Creating new assets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_EditingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH6-SW2)" chapter, which deals with merging two pieces of video together.

There's also a video cropping class you could use to produce the segments you want to merge later with AVMutableComposition: [UIVideoEditorController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Look for the AVEditDemo sample from WWDC 2010 for some code examples.

Comment: anybody knows where I can download the AVEditDemo, I have tried to find that sample code for hours

Comment: The AVEditDemo sample is in the WWDC 2010 sample code pack - you should find it somewhere on Apple's iOS developer page. Or, if you only want that sample, download it from here: http://ge.tt/86NpOV7?c