# iphone AVEditDemo or any video processing examples

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I am trying to process videos in some way:

- Cut and merge videos.
- Record the screen and make the video out of that recording.

I look up on the Internet and stackoverflow as well and see that there is a code sample from apple called AVEditDemo but I could never find it out. If anybody has that example and willing to share with me or has any similar examples that can teach me how to do the 2 above jobs, it would be excellent.

I see there are some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633547/cut-videos-and-merge-them-using-objective-c), but I would love to have the code sample. It would help me move forward quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a WWDC 2010 video called [Editing Media with AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010) which may be useful to you and is available through the Developer Portal.

The AVEditDemo application is included in the WWDC 2010 Sample Code because it goes with the video. This should contain the AVEditDemo Application which goes with the Video. Unfortunately you need to download all the WWDC 2010 Sample Code to get it (232.6mb). You can get the entire download of all the code here: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

Comment: I think that the WWDC '11 session 415 "Working with Media in AV Foundation" supersedes the '10 video and it appears to use the same sample code for the first half of the session.

Comment: where could you find the links to the actual sample codes & videos?

Comment: @headkit, if you're asking about the 2011 session mentioned by Mark Thalman, the video and sample code are at https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/. You have to be a registered Apple developer to see them.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Is video still available in 2021? Couldn't find any session mentioned in topic.
Only found WWDC 10 projects on github https://github.com/master-nevi/WWDC-2010/tree/master/AVEditDemo