# how to add text on video in iPhone

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, watermark, video-editing

I want to add a text or string ON the video being played by MPMoviePlayerViewController in a way that it becomes part of the video being played. So that, when I post that video on Facebook or Twitter the text must be shown above the video.

For this I have tried getting all the frames of the video and then write text on each of those frames and then again make a video of all those frames. But this way, I am getting memory issues and it crashes on the device.

```
    - (NSArray*)getVideoFramesFromMovieController:(MPMoviePlayerViewController*)mpMoviePlayerVC
{       NSLog(@"Getting frames from a video asset.");

    //  videoFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *videoFrames = [NSMutableArray array];


    for(float i= 0; i <= mpMoviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.duration; )
    {
        UIImage *singleFrameImage = [mpMoviePlayerVC.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:i timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];



        [videoFrames addObject:singleFrameImage];

        NSLog(@"Got frame number : %d",[videoFrames count]);

        i = i + (1/self.frameRate) ;    //frame capturing duration i.e. 15fps  //self.frameRate

    }
    NSLog(@"Total frames: %d",[videoFrames count]);
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:videoFrames];
}
```

Method above gives me all the frames, i write a text on all those text, say "hello", and then make a video of all these frames.

```
    -(void)writeImageAsMovie:(NSArray *)array toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size
{
    NSLog(@"Inside writeImageAsMovie method.");

    NSError *error              = nil;


    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter  = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                              error:&error];


    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,   
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,   
                                   nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];



    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];


    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];


    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];


    dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
    int __block         frame = 0;

    [writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{
        while ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
        {
            NSLog(@"Total frames to be written: %d",[array count]);
            if(++frame >= [array count])   //total frames
            {
                [writerInput markAsFinished];
                [videoWriter finishWriting];
                [videoWriter release];
                break;
            }

            CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[array objectAtIndex:frame]CGImage] andSize:size];
            if (buffer)
            {
                if(![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frame, self.frameRate)])
                    NSLog(@"FAIL");
                else
                    NSLog(@"Success:%d", frame);
                CFRelease(buffer);
            }
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"outside for loop");


    [self performSelector:@selector(waitTillVideoFinishes) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];
}
```

It is working fine on the mac, but crashes on the device because of memory issues.

I'hv also tried various ways to watermark the text on the video but could not get through. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "writing" on a video like this would mean decompressing the necessary frames to bitmaps, drawing the text, then recompressing the video. this is not a cheap operation, particularly on a resource constrained device like a phone.

Comment: Is there any other efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you need this text to be a permanent part of the video, especially when you're doing it client-side? If it was a security watermark, it should be done on the server. If you're simply doing (say) a subtitle, then have ios float some text over the video, much as youtube's ads and annotations do.

Comment: I need it to be part of my video so that when i post this video on Facebook it is shown there.

Comment: You can find your answer here.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190333/how-can-i-add-overlay-text-on-a-video-then-re-encode-it/15308258#15308258][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190333/how-can-i-add-overlay-text-on-a-video-then-re-encode-it/15308258#15308258

Answer (score 2):

This code is add a text or string ON the video and after saving video you will play on any player.
Most Advantage of this code is Provide video with sound.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

-(void)MixVideoWithText
{
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    //If you need audio as well add the Asset Track for audio here

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    CGSize sizeOfVideo=[videoAsset naturalSize];
    //NSLog(@"sizeOfVideo.width is %f",sizeOfVideo.width);
    //NSLog(@"sizeOfVideo.height is %f",sizeOfVideo.height);
    //TextLayer defines the text they want to add in Video

    CATextLayer *textOfvideo=[[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    textOfvideo.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];//text is shows the text that you want add in video.
    [textOfvideo setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fontUsed] size:13])];//fontUsed is the name of font
    [textOfvideo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height/6)];
    [textOfvideo setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [textOfvideo setForegroundColor:[selectedColour CGColor]];


    CALayer *optionalLayer=[CALayer layer];
    [optionalL addSublayer:textOfvideo];
    optionalL.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    [optionalL setMasksToBounds:YES];

    CALayer *parentLayer=[CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    videoLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:optionalLayer];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition=[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;
    videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 10);
    videoComposition.renderSize=sizeOfVideo;
    videoComposition.animationTool=[AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/utput_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.videoComposition=videoComposition;

    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status)
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Export OK");
            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath)) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            }
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportSession.error);
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
            break;
    }
  }];
}
```

Shows the error they will come after saving video.

```
-(void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo 
{
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, But I just had the same requirement and I could not find any really easy and fast solution (in order to quickly test that I can do it) until I found this [GPUImage issue: #110](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/110).

Brad Larson is suggesting, that using [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) it is possible to record a video with existing filters or/and UIKit elements on video.

So based on information in issue #110, I combined GPUImage FilterShowcase project with SimpleVideoFilter project to quickly test if that is possible.

**And it works, of course.**

So I am writing this answer to provide quick sample how to do it:

Open up FilterShowcase project,

Open up ShowcaseFilterViewController.m file, and find `else if (filterType == GPUIMAGE_UIELEMENT)`

and after the code You will find there - add this code:

```
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];

[blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];

double delayToStartRecording = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t startTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToStartRecording * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(startTime2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"Start recording");

    videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieWriter startRecording];

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t stopTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(stopTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [blendFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
        [movieWriter finishRecording];
        NSLog(@"Movie completed");

         UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, NULL, NULL);
    });
});

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];

return;
```

After that, compile FilterShowCase project on iPhone, and choose `UI element` from the list. Then after about 7-10 seconds there will be a video saved in Your Photos library.

Comment: How can i add watermark at specific time my video is 60 sec. and i want to add watermark from 10 to 50 sec. please help me