# CATextLayer not visible on video in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, video-editing

I'm working on a video app that generates a credits clip using a .mov resource as the background and a CATextLayer for the credits. The code works in iOS 5 and 6, but not in iOS 7 - ie: the clip gets generated but text does not appear.

I've tried using the code from the answer to this question ([How can I add overlay text on a video, then re-encode it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190333/how-can-i-add-overlay-text-on-a-video-then-re-encode-it/15308258#15308258)), but the text in the CATextLayer still does not show up.

Why is iOS 7 behaving differently and how can I get it to work?

Comment: I tried to solve it for 2 days and I couldn't get it working

Comment: It only work if I set the foreground color to yellow and the background color to white. Weird!!!!

Comment: @Rob VS, funny enough people usually thank the question answerer but all too often I am very grateful for the person who asked the question in the first place. Thanks for saving me from 30 mins of head scratching!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After 2 days on this problem

```
CATextLayer *text = [CATextLayer layer];
text.string = @"Your Text";
text.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithFontName((CFStringRef)@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight");
text.font = font;
text.fontSize = 20;
text.foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[text display];
[aLayer addSublayer:text];
[aLayer display];
```

The secret is calling [CALayer display] method

Comment: Holy crap!! [CALayer display] and [CATextLayer display] did the trick. I had just converted my code to mimic Apple's AVSimpleEditoriOS sample code and it still didn't work (just about the only diff was the .mov file to which I was adding titles). btw, Apple's code does not call 'display'. Thank dude!!

Comment: I would recommend using displayIfNeeded instead of display, as display is not supposed to be called directly.

Comment: Thank you.  This magically solved it for me after too long banging my head on my desk.

Comment: Haha, 3 years later and this is still saving the day! Thanks @MAMN84

Comment: save my day and night :). Thanks

Comment: 2023... still the same issue. But this works! Thanks a lot!