# Add Text to individual segments of video using SCRecorder in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Im using this wildly popular library for recording segments of video like Vine: https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder

It works great and in the demo it adds a watermark to all videos created, but the problem is it adds the mark to all segments of the current session. I would like to be able to allow users to add text captions similar to Snapchat on the individual segments. I came across this post when searching, but im lost as to how to apply it to a individual segment: [How can I add overlay text on a video, then re-encode it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190333/how-can-i-add-overlay-text-on-a-video-then-re-encode-it)

Im not looking for someone to spoon feed me a full answer, just looking for a AVFoundation master to give me a rough abstract overview of the steps that would be involved to do this....with that I can do the research and try to figure it out myself.

Comment: No longer needed, figured it out.

Comment: You should post an answer, maybe it will help future users.

Comment: Do I get my 50 points back if i answer my own question?

Comment: You can't award the bounty to yourself, but you may have some luck getting a refund if you flag for a moderator and explain the situation.