# Can't show animated CALayer in video using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool

Tags: swift, calayer, cabasicanimation, avassetexportsession, avvideocomposition

UPDATE 6:
I've managed to fix my issue completely but I still would like a better explanation than what I'm guessing is the reason it didn't work if I'm incorrect

I've been trying to animate a sprite sheet over a video but every time I export the video the end result is the sample video I start with.

Here's my code:

First up my custom CALayer to handle my own sprite sheets

```swift
class SpriteLayer: CALayer {
    var frameIndex: Int

    override init() {
        // Using 0 as a default state
        self.frameIndex = 0
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.frameIndex = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func display() {
        let currentFrameIndex = self.frameIndex
        if currentFrameIndex == 0 {
            return
        }
        let frameSize = self.contentsRect.size
        self.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(currentFrameIndex - 1) * frameSize.height, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
    }

    override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == "contentsRect" {
            return nil
        }
        return super.action(forKey: event)
    }

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        return key == "frameIndex"
    }
}
```

Gif is a basic class with nothing fancy and works just fine. `gif.Strip` is a `UIImage` of a vertical sprite sheet representing the gif.

Now comes the method that should export a new video (it is part of a larger class used for exporting.

```swift
func convertAndExport(to url :URL , completion: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        // Get Initial info and make sure our destination is available
        self.outputURL = url
        let stripCgImage = self.gif.strip!.cgImage!
        // This is used to time how long the export took
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
        } catch {
            print("Remove Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            print(error)
        }
        // Find and load "sample.mp4" as a AVAsset
        let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp4")!
        let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
        let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
        // Start a new mutable Composition with the same base video track
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
        let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        do {
            try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {
            print("Insert Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform
        // Quick access to the video size
        let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize
        // Setup CALayer and it's animation
        let aLayer = SpriteLayer()
        aLayer.contents = stripCgImage
        aLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        aLayer.opacity = 1.0
        aLayer.masksToBounds = true
        aLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        aLayer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1.0 / 3.0)
        let spriteAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "frameIndex")
        spriteAnimation.fromValue = 1
        spriteAnimation.toValue = 4
        spriteAnimation.duration = 2.25
        spriteAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        spriteAnimation.autoreverses = false
        spriteAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
        aLayer.add(spriteAnimation, forKey: nil)
        // Setup Layers for AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
        let parentLayer = CALayer()
        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)
        // Create the mutable video composition
        let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
        videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
        // Set the video composition to apply to the composition's video track
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
        let videoTrack = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        videoComp.instructions = [instruction]
        // Initialize export session
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
        assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        assetExport.outputURL = self.outputURL
        assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        // Export
        assetExport.exportAsynchronously {
            let status = assetExport.status
            switch status {
            case .failed:
                print("Export Failed")
                print("Export Error: \(assetExport.error!.localizedDescription)")
                print(assetExport.error!)
            case .unknown:
                print("Export Unknown")
            case .exporting:
                print("Export Exporting")
            case .waiting:
                print("Export Waiting")
            case .cancelled:
                print("Export Cancelled")
            case .completed:
                let end = DispatchTime.now()
                let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
                let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
                // Function is now over, we can print how long it took
                print("Time to generate video: \(timeInterval) seconds")
                completion()
            }
        }
}
```

EDIT:
I based my code on the following links

- [SpriteLayer and how to use it](https://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/)
- [CABasicAnimation on a video](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2734-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)
- [Using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool and AVAssetExportSession to save the new video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308258/4350037)

UPDATE 1:
I've tried removing the `CABasicAnimation` part of my code and played around with my `CALayer` but to no avail. I can't even get the image to show up.
To test things out I tried animating this sprite sheet using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` on `contentsRect` in a Xcode Playground and it worked fine so I don't think the issue is with the CABasicAnimation, and maybe not even with the `CALayer` itself. I could really use some help on this because I don't understand why I can't even get an image to show over my sample video on the export.

UPDATE 2:
In response to matt's comment I've tried forgetting about the sprite sheet for a bit and changed it into a `CATextLayer` but still not seeing anything on my video (it has dark images so white text should be perfectly visible)

```swift
let aLayer = CATextLayer()
aLayer.string = "This is a test"
aLayer.fontSize = videoSize.height / 6
aLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
aLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
aLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height / 6)
```

UPDATE 3:
As per Matt's request I tried changing `parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)` to `videoLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)` but still nothing changed, but I thought as much because the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool/1389594-init) for the `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` is as follows

```swift
convenience init(postProcessingAsVideoLayer videoLayer: CALayer, 
              in animationLayer: CALayer)
```

meaning my `parentLayer` is it's `animationLayer` and probably means any animations should be done in this layer.

UPDATE 4:
I'm starting to go crazy over here, I've given up for now the idea of showing text or an animated image I just want to affect my video in any way possible so I changed `aLayer` to this:

```swift
let aLayer = CALayer()
aLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
aLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Well, this does absolutely nothing, I still get my sample video at my outputUrl (I started testing this in a playground with the following code if you want to "play" along)

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

func convertAndExport(to url :URL , completion: @escaping () -> Void ) {
    let start = DispatchTime.now()
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        print("Remove Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        print(error)
    }

    let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp4")!
    let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
    let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!

    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print("Insert Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        print(error)
        return
    }
    compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform
    let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize
    print("Video Size Detected: \(videoSize.width) x \(videoSize.height)")

    let aLayer = CALayer()
    aLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
    aLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)
    aLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
    assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    assetExport.outputURL = url
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronously {
        let status = assetExport.status
        switch status {
        case .failed:
            print("Export Failed")
            print("Export Error: \(assetExport.error!.localizedDescription)")
            print(assetExport.error!)
        case .unknown:
            print("Export Unknown")
        case .exporting:
            print("Export Exporting")
        case .waiting:
            print("Export Waiting")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export Cancelled")
        case .completed:
            let end = DispatchTime.now()
            let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
            let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
            print("Time to generate video: \(timeInterval) seconds")
            completion()
        }
    }
}

let outputUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.mp4")
convertAndExport(to: outputUrl) {
    print(outputUrl)
}
```

Please someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong...

UPDATE 5:
I am running everything except playground tests from an iPad Air 2 (so no simulator) because I use the camera to take pictures and then stitch them into a sprite sheet I then planned on animating on a video I would send by email. I started doing Playground testing because every test from the iPad required me to go through the whole app cycle (countdown, photos, form, email sending/receiving)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, Finally got it to work as I always wanted it to.

First off even if he deleted his comments, thanks to Matt for the link to a working example that helped me piece together what was wrong with my code.

- First off

```swift
let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
```

I needed to use `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` instead of `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`. My guess is that the passthrough preset means you don't do any re-encoding so setting it to highest (not medium because my exported video is of over 400x400) made it so that I could actually re-encode my video. I'm guessing this is what was stopping the exported video from containing any of the `CALayer` I was trying out (even covering the video in white).

- Secondly (not sure if this affects really but I'll try later)

```swift
parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)
```

I replaced this with:

```swift
videoLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)
```

Not sure if this really mattered but my understanding was that this was actually the animation layer for `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` and `parentLayer` was just a container not meant to contain more than this, but I'm likely wrong.

- Third change I did

```swift
let spriteAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "frameIndex")
spriteAnimation.fromValue = 1
spriteAnimation.toValue = 4
spriteAnimation.duration = 2.25
spriteAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
spriteAnimation.autoreverses = false
spriteAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
aLayer.add(spriteAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

I changed it to this:

```swift
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.contentsRect))
animation.duration = 2.25
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.values = [
    CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1/3.0),
    CGRect(x: 0, y: 1/3.0, width: 1, height: 1/3.0),
    CGRect(x: 0, y: 2/3.0, width: 1, height: 1/3.0)
    ] as [CGRect]
animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
aLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

This change was mainly removing my custom animations for the sprite sheet (since it will always be the same I first wanted a working example then I'll generalise it and probably add it to my private UI Pod). But most importantly `animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false` I noticed that removing this makes it so the animation simply does not play on the exported video. So for anyone with `CABasicAnimation` not animating on the video after an export, try looking if your `isRemovedOnCompletion` is set correctly on your animation.

I think that's pretty much all the changed I did.

Although I technically answered my question my bounty remains to understand how `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` and `AVAssetExport` work and why I had to do the changes I did to finally get it to work if anyone is interested in explaining.

Thanks again to Matt, you helped me out by showing me how you did it.

Comment: You saved my day by mentioning that AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough breaks any layers you add, it works now, thanks ❤️

Comment: @james how do you set `animation.isRemovedOnCompletion` on a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`? Its a read only variable according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation/1412458-removedoncompletion